# Web scraping- how can i get the price of all the available posts in a web page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code was provided for me, it gives back a lot of info about one post i want to use it to get the same info in this [url](https://haraj.com.sa/tags/%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1) and increase the posts number in this page now it's only 20

```
import requests


# https://haraj.com.sa/1179070147

def main(url):
    params = {
        'queryName': 'detailsPosts_singlePost',
        'token': '',
        'clientid': '812f41b2-9936-4405-aa9c-378db19b8cc4',
        'version': '8.2.9 , 10 18 - 7 - 21'
    }
    data = {
        "query": "query($ids:[Int]) { posts( id:$ids) {\n\t\titems {\n\t\t\tid status authorUsername title city postDate updateDate hasImage thumbURL authorId bodyHTML bodyTEXT city tags imagesList commentStatus commentCount upRank downRank geoHash\n\t\t}\n\t\tpageInfo {\n\t\t\thasNextPage\n\t\t}\n\t\t} }",
        "variables": {
            "ids": [
                79070147
            ]
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(url, params=params, json=data)
    print(r.json())


main('https://graphql.haraj.com.sa/')
```

any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear for other readers, However you are going to receive a multiple down-votes due to that. BTW, i provided an answer for you since i myself understood your goal because i been the one who provided a previous answer for you. But i myself will down-vote your question right now and upvote to close it since it's unclear for others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the pages in order to obtain the desired information.

> Note, you can pickup all information from the JSON response directly without needs to call the API again.

```py
import requests
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)

        for page in range(1, 3): # increase the number of pages from here.
            params = {
                'queryName': 'detailsPosts_tag_page{}'.format(page),
                'token': '',
                'clientid': '812f41b2-9936-4405-aa9c-378db19b8cc4',
                'version': '8.2.9 , 10 18 - 7 - 21'
            }
            data = {
                "query": "query($tag:String,$page:Int) { posts( tag:$tag, page:$page) {\n\t\titems {\n\t\t\tid status authorUsername title city postDate updateDate hasImage thumbURL authorId bodyHTML bodyTEXT city tags imagesList commentStatus commentCount upRank downRank geoHash geoCity geoNeighborhood\n\t\t}\n\t\tpageInfo {\n\t\t\thasNextPage\n\t\t}\n\t\t} }",
                "variables": {
                    "page": page,
                    "tag": "حراج العقار"
                }
            }
            r = req.post(url, params=params, json=data)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                for i in r.json()['data']['posts']['items']:
                    pp(i)
                    # check i.keys()
            else:
                exit(f"Page# {page} is not exist, However program stopped.")


main('https://graphql.haraj.com.sa/')
```